# Python tile based game (2d array) player movement

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a rougelike in pygame, and I'm having trouble with player movement in a grid. This sample program shows how I plan to do it:

```
class P:

    def __init__(self, standing_on):
        self.standing_on = standing_on
        self.row, self.column = 4, 4

    def __str__(self):
        return "@"


class G:
    walkable = True

    def __str__(self):
        return "█"


class W:
    walkable = False

    def __str__(self):
        return "|"

p = P(G())
game_map = [
    [W(), W(), W(), W(), W(), W(), W(), W(), W(), W()],
    [W(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), W()],
    [W(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), W()],
    [W(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), W()],
    [W(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), W()],
    [W(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), W()],
    [W(), G(), p,   G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), W()],
    [W(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), W()],
    [W(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), W()],
    [W(), W(), W(), W(), W(), W(), W(), W(), W(), W()]
]


def print_map():
    for column in range(10):
        for row in range(10):
            print(game_map[column][row], end="")
        print()


def move_up():
    temp = p.row - 1
    if game_map[temp][p.column].walkable:
        game_map[p.column][p.row] = p.standing_on
        p.column -= 1
        p.standing_on = game_map[p.column][p.row]
        game_map[p.column][p.row] = p


print_map()
print(p.row, p.column, "\n")
move_up()
print_map()
print(p.row, p.column, "\n")
move_up()
print_map()
print(p.row, p.column, "\n")
```

- p = player
- g = grass
- w = wall

and the output:

```
||||||||||
|████████|
|████████|
|████████|
|████████|
|████████|
|█@██████|
|████████|
|████████|
||||||||||
4 4

||||||||||
|████████|
|████████|
|███@████|
|████████|
|████████|
|█@██████|
|████████|
|████████|
||||||||||
4 3

||||||||||
|████████|
|███@████|
|████████|
|████████|
|████████|
|█@██████|
|████████|
|████████|
||||||||||
4 2
```

The numbers under the map represent the players coordinates. I start at 4, 4 (note that its 0 indexed) and move up twice. When displayed the map is completely wrong though, and I have tested it in my actual game and get the same bug, using images instead of text. Any idea whats going on?

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't a debugging service. Fun problem though. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your starting position. You need to draw a map without your player and then place the player on the map. Here is the solution that works:

```
class P:
   def __init__(self, standing_on):
       self.standing_on = standing_on
       self.row, self.column = 4, 4

   def __str__(self):
       return "@"


class G:
    walkable = True

    def __str__(self):
        return "█"


class W:
    walkable = False

    def __str__(self):
        return "|"

p = P(G())
game_map = [
    [W(), W(), W(), W(), W(), W(), W(), W(), W(), W()],
    [W(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), W()],
    [W(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), W()],
    [W(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), W()],
    [W(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), W()],
    [W(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), W()],
    [W(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), W()],
    [W(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), W()],
    [W(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), G(), W()],
    [W(), W(), W(), W(), W(), W(), W(), W(), W(), W()]
]


def print_map():
    game_map[p.column][p.row] = p
    for column in range(10):
        for row in range(10):
            print(game_map[column][row], end="")
        print()

def move_up():
    temp = p.row - 1
    if game_map[temp][p.column].walkable:
        game_map[p.column][p.row] = p.standing_on
        p.column -= 1
        p.standing_on = game_map[p.column][p.row]


print_map()
print(p.row, p.column, "\n")
move_up()
print_map()
print(p.row, p.column, "\n")
move_up()
print_map()
print(p.row, p.column, "\n")
```

Comment: Thanks! why does this matter though?

Comment: You were always setting two players. One in game map and the second one in move_up function. But you need the game map without a player and then draw that player with every print_map call (first row in print_map function). The position of the player which you have set in the game_map was not changing and the first position (4,4) of the second player, which was correctly moving, was never drawn.